# What are serial threads/task called?

Tags: multithreading

Whats it called when you have multiple task that are very quick to execute but instead of having real threads you just toss them into some task based queue which will execute them serially. The more cores you have the faster the queue can be consumed. I know theres a name for it but i cant remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of a [Serial Dispatch Queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)?